# SQL only returning rows with data, not the ones that are 0

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to report on how many items sit in a specific status. 
The code ive got only returns the rows that have a value in them and not the ones that dont.

```
SELECT Department
       ,Status
       ,count(Department) AS "Number in status" 
       ,convert(VARCHAR, getdate(), 103) AS "Date report ran"
FROM [Server name].[xxx].[Database name]
WHERE STATUS NOT IN (
              'Closed'
              ,'Cancelled'
              )
       AND Department IN (
              'Department name'
              )
GROUP BY Department,Status

ORDER BY CASE 
              WHEN STATUS = 'Open'
                     THEN 1
              WHEN STATUS = 'In Progress'
                     THEN 2
              WHEN STATUS = 'Authorised'
                     THEN 3
              WHEN STATUS = 'Awaiting Auth'
                     THEN 4
              WHEN STATUS = 'Awaiting Collection'
                     THEN 5
              WHEN STATUS = 'Awaiting Delivery'
                     THEN 6
              WHEN STATUS = 'Awaiting Development'
                     THEN 7
              WHEN STATUS = 'Awaiting Engineer'
                     THEN 8
              WHEN STATUS = 'Awaiting Invoice/Credit'
                     THEN 9
              WHEN STATUS = 'Awaiting Quote'
                     THEN 10
              WHEN STATUS = 'Cancelled'
                     THEN 11
              WHEN STATUS = 'Chase End User'
                     THEN 12
              WHEN STATUS = 'Final Chase End User'
                     THEN 13
              WHEN STATUS = 'Closed'
                     THEN 14
              WHEN STATUS = 'Future Requirements'
                     THEN 15
              WHEN STATUS = 'In Test'
                     THEN 16
              WHEN STATUS = 'Next Release'
                     THEN 17
                     WHEN STATUS = 'On Hold'
                     THEN 18
                     WHEN STATUS = 'With End-User'
                     THEN 22
                     WHEN STATUS = 'With IIT'
                     THEN 23
                     WHEN STATUS = 'Processing Via Demand Management'
                     THEN 27
              END;
```

The results are below but it doesnt include all of the other status' that  may have a 0 value:

```
+-----------------+----------------------------------+----+------------+
|                 |                                  |    |            |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+----+------------+
| Department name | Open                             | 92 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | In Progress                      |  9 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | Awaiting Development             |  4 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | Future Requirements              |  1 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | In Test                          |  7 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | On Hold                          | 15 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | With End-User                    | 28 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | With IIT                         |  2 | 29/03/2019 |
| Department name | Processing Via Demand Management |  2 | 29/03/2019 |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+----+------------+
```

Comment: As the saying goes, "There is no row". Every row in your output is a representation of a group formed from *1* or more input rows.

Comment: You could create a table with all possible status and create an outer join.

Answer (score 2):

You need a status table, containing at least the status description and (probably) the reporting order:

```
CREATE TABLE Statuses (
    Status varchar(30) not null,
    ReportOrder int not null,
    ShowInReport bit not null,
    constraint PK_Statuses (Status)
)
```

And now you can write your query using a `LEFT JOIN` from that table to your other unnamed table (since your query currently claims to be querying a *database* rather than a table in its `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT Department
       ,s.Status
       ,count(Department) AS "Number in status" 
       ,convert(VARCHAR, getdate(), 103) AS "Date report ran"
FROM
    Statuses s
       left join
    unnamedTable t
       on
          s.Status = t.Status
WHERE s.ShowInReport = 1
       AND Department IN (
              'Department name'
              )
GROUP BY Department,s.Status
ORDER BY s.ReportOrder
```

It may also be prudent to have a `Departments` table too if you still want department names in the output for the `0` rows, to be used very similarly to the above:

```
...
FROM
    Statuses s
       cross join
    Departments d
       left join
    unnamedTable t
       on
          s.Status = t.Status and
          d.Department = t.Department
...
```

(You should also have a FK between the unnamed table and `Statuses` to ensure that all status values used in it are valid)

Answer (score 0):

If your database is well designed, your status and departement are into a seperated table that you joined with you record. So instead of doing a natural join, you want to do :

Departement X Status -> You get all departement and status combinaison possible
And you do a LEFT JOIN on the resulting table with your record.
Then you group by departement and status as you do and do a count.

Comment: See -Damien_The_Unbeliever answer for more details.